# C++ windows system ("path") not working if there is space somewhere

Tags: c++, windows, file, path, system

My path to the executable file is:

```
C:\Users\FirstName LastName\Desktop\Saturated.exe
```

My program is:

```
while (s != "Exit")
{
    cin >> s;
    system (s.c_str());
}
```

Where s is string.

I tried to write:

```
C:\\Users\\FirstName LastName\\Desktop\\Saturated.exe

\"C:\\Users\\FirstName LastName\\Desktop\\Saturated.exe\"

C:/Users/FirstName LastName/Desktop/Saturated.exe
```

But none of this worked because of space between `FirstName` and `LastName`. What should I do?

Comment: when you pass an argument containing spaces you need to wrap it in quotes so your second try should have worked. probably best to show us exactly how you're doing it.

Comment: Try escaping it, maybe it works. "C:\\Users\\FirstName\ LastName\\Desktop\\Saturated.exe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used the command line arguments to input the string, your OS would parse it correctly. If you want to input the path while running the program, your best chance is to go with `std::getline`, you'll read the whole line no matter what, no need for `"`.

Or, if you want to implement that same parsing behavior, you'll check if the first character is `"` (with `cin.peek()`), if that's the case, you'll `cin.ignore()` and `std::getline` until another `"`, otherwise you'll just `cin >> s;`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used getline (cin, s) and  C:/Users/"FirstName LastName"/Desktop/Saturated.exe
And it works.

Comment: It is safer to use backslashes than forward slashes.  Support for using forward slashes in Windows is somewhat erratic.